# Как построить подобное дерево?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Код мне не нужен, я хочу понять лишь логику построения подобного дерева.
Конкретно для этой картинки я даже исходный код видел, но там рекурсия и много-много методов из обширной коллекции, а так же добавляются значения в массивы и потом каждый элемент в нескольких циклах перебирается ещё в нескольких циклах.. То есть понят смысл не получается. А я прошу, если Вас не затруднит, объяснить на словах алгоритм построения.[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Что является входными данными? Что на выходе? Рекурсия это самый простой способ работы с деревьями. Итеративные методы понять обычно тяжелее (к примеру, можно на реализации quicksort посмотреть). Если у вас концепция рекурсии затруднения вызывает, то я бы порешал простые задачи, где в решении эффективно рекурсия может использоваться: [вот пример генерации  дерева директории в формате html на Питоне  с использованием рекурсивной функции (функция простая -- если она не ясна, то необходимо улучшить понимание рекурсии).](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10961991/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Окей, давайте подумаем. Для того, чтобы построить такое дерево, надо знать ширину (то есть, в вашем случае высоту, вертикальный размер) каждого поддерева на каждом из уровней. Легко видеть, что размеры поддеревьев независимы.

Для листовых элементов ширина очевидна. Поднимаясь на уровень выше, вам сверстать поддерево. Вы для начала располагаете все дочерние элементы рядом (при этом помещая их поддеревья на соответствующую высоту), и смотрите, есть ли перекрытия. Если нет, всё хорошо. Если есть, вам нужно раздвинуть дочерние элементы так, чтобы перекрытий не было.

Вот по идее и всё. Дальше рекурсия до корня.

Comment: > и смотрите, есть ли перекрытия  

Хочу уточнить, Вы предлагаете смотреть по координатам? Или что Вы имеете ввиду под 

> есть ли перекрытия

Comment: @vas: Ага. Смотрите, если допустим узлы второго уровня расположить рядом, один над другом, то узлы третьего уровня будут налазить друг на друга. Видите?

Answer (score 1):

Идентифицировал источник дерева как [d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)

Жаль но большинство реализаций динамических графических деревьев/графов в JavaScript становятся малопригодными в реальности где-то после добавления 1000+ элементов и 30-40 уровней рекурсии.

Чтобы построить его нужно просто рекурсивно обойти все списки с данными(которые хранятся в JSON или еще в какой-то разметке) и для каждого списка вызвать процедуру отрисовки. Кроме этого нужны еще методы для добавления/удаления узлов в разметку, обновления отрисовки дерева после добавления узлов и скрытия/показвыния уже существующих узлов.

Как-то так. Звучит легко, но на деле это довольно много кода и в процессе можно наткнуться на очень много неприятностей

Comment: У меня нет json и я не на js пытаюсь воссоздать подобное. По этому и спрашиваю о алгоритме. И именно это дерево, на мой взгляд, лучше всех справится с большим объемом узлов. Все остальные что я видел, смотрятся не так убедительно.

Comment: Так json можно и не в js использовать, это ведь просто формат для древовидной разметки, куски дерева можно вообще хоть в бинарнике хранить. А по поводу алгоритма, то он собственно только один: рекурсивный обход списков + отрисовка на каждом этапе.

Comment: Если бы он был нарисован при помощи "отрисовка на каждом этапе", то узлы бы залазили друг на друга. Точно так же, как в подобных алгоритмах не используют координаты, а только ширину и высоту ветвей.

Comment: Ну так вы же знаете на каждой итерации глубину и номер текущего списка. Они так или иначе преобразуются в координаты/ширину/высоту, этим и должна заниматься процедура отрисовки. Преобразовывать адресацию в то что можно увидеть.